# Failed to load module for python script when launching via Jenkins

Tags: python, jenkins, cygwin, python-import

I am trying to import **scipy** and **numpy** in my python script. 
And the script is triggered by Jenkins on one of the windows slave machine with cygwin python3.4 installed.

I have successfully ran the script through cygwin terminal on the slave itself
But cannot triggered the script via Jenkins with the following command on Jenkins' build:

```
python3 $PATH_TO_THE_SCRIPT/test_python.py
```

There are only 3 lines in "test_python.py"

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys, os
import sounddevice
import scipy.io.wavfile
```

which gives me an error on Jenkins

```
Building remotely on client1 (test_recording) in workspace c:/jenkins/workspace/sound_check_recording
next nodes: [][sound_check_recording] $ sh -xe C:\cygwin64\tmp\hudson7552321748368548110.sh
+ python3 c:/cygwin64/lib/python3.4/test_python.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/cygwin64/lib/python3.4/test_python.py", line 4, in <module>
    import scipy.io.wavfile
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/scipy/__init__.py", line 61, in <module>
    from numpy import show_config as show_numpy_config
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 170, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .polynomial import *
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/polynomial.py", line 19, in <module>
    from numpy.linalg import eigvals, lstsq, inv
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/linalg/__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
    from .linalg import *
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py", line 29, in <module>
    from numpy.linalg import lapack_lite, _umath_linalg
ImportError: No such file or directory
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

I did check in the file system but did not find anything missing in the package. 
It seems like a PATH issue. Does anybody have had a same issue when using Jenkins and Cygwin python? Any feedback is welcome.

Comment: did you install the dependencies?

Comment: Probably this page contains a clue: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SSH+slaves+and+Cygwin

Comment: Thanks, but I have found the solution. I should install the Cygwin package through jenkins in order to make the PATH correct. I don't know why but it works